# how to query closed session in vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

Is there a way to query closed session record in vertica database?
It seem there is only a table store the current active sessions:

```
select * from sessions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the `dc_session_ends` table.

```
SELECT * FROM dc_session_ends;
```

It shows the time the session was closed, the node the session was on, the session_id and the user_id/user_name.

To test it, you can query your current session_id.

```sql
SELECT session_id FROM current_session;
```

If you query the `dc_session_ends` table with that session_id nothing will show up, but if you close your session, and then reconnect, you will see the session_id appear.

```
SELECT * FROM dc_session_ends WHERE session_id = '<session_id>';
```